# Getting null is not an object in react native on native modules

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to write a function in Java that is exposed to the JavaScript in react native.
I have done the exact instructions as mentioned in the `https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android`
but i still get the same error:

```
typeError: null is not an object(evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.{myModule}.{myExposeFunction}'.
```

I am running the application on an android phone.
I have uploaded the code:

1. App.js - https://pastebin.com/raw/Aq0CARR1
2. ToastModule.java - https://pastebin.com/raw/93bmqbz6
3. ToastManger.java - https://pastebin.com/raw/fPfFEdBB
4. MainApplication.java - https://pastebin.com/raw/uwGR86aM
   as well as i have created another file ToastExample.js:

   import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
   module.exports = NativeModules.ToastExample;

Comment: did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a code snippet of the function or methods giving the error? It's hard to tell what may be happening without being able to see the affected code.

Comment: I have uploaded the code, i will glad if you can help